# Local storage for Blazor Server 8

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, local-storage, asp.net-core-8

I am encountering some issues configuring local storage in Blazor .NET Core 8. After updating my project, I found that since the pages are now created on the server, it's not possible to access the browser's local storage.

I have tried using Blazored Local Storage, JavaScript, and ProtectedSessionStorage, but none seem to be effective. Additionally, I attempted to configure the page to not pre-render in the following manner:

@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender:false))

I use the local storage a lot to update the cart shop from the website.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Jair

Here's a video of what happend when I try to create a shop cart using the local storage

https://somup.com/cZeFlFCjbr

I have the use the local storage during the process because is how  i send the information between pages. My code bellow:

In this part I call the method cart

[image]

This is the local storage service

[image]

Comment: Strange. ProtectedSessionStorage should only work on the Server. You will indeed need InteractiveSerever rendering.

Comment: Set up a [mre]: create a new project and show all steps on top of the template.

Comment: I update the description, see if is better to understand

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ProtectedLocalStorage` in blazor server rendermode, Just try following in a per page/component project:

```
@page "/"
@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false))
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedLocalStorage ProtectedLocalStore
@value
@code {
    int value;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await ProtectedLocalStore.SetAsync("count", 7);       //set value to localstorage
        var result = await ProtectedLocalStore.GetAsync<int>("count");   //get value to localstorage
        value = result.Value;
    }
}
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: I have to call de local storage during the client process, so I cant do this way. I update the description, see if is better to understand

Comment: @JairVieiraJunior Do you mean you also have client project, so you need to access localstorage in both client and server project? I think you could use protected localstroage in server and blazored.localstorage in client.

Comment: Actually I just need on the client project, but when I try to use blazored.localstorage, the page stop to work and lost connection with the server. It seems to work only when i use in After Render Async method

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying method calls by removing unnecessary parameters or specifications reduces the risk of errors during code modifications. If the return type of GetLocalDataAsync ever changes, the impact on the calling code is minimized, as type expectations are managed within the method itself.

```
public class LocalDataService
{
    private readonly ProtectedLocalStorage _protectedLocalStorage;
    
    public LocalDataService(ProtectedLocalStorage protectedLocalStorage)
    {
        _protectedLocalStorage = protectedLocalStorage;
    }

    public async Task StoreLocalDataAsync(string data)
    {
        await _protectedLocalStorage.SetAsync("localdata", data);
        
    }

    public async Task<string> GetLocalDataAsync()
    {
        var result = await _protectedLocalStorage.GetAsync<string>("localdata");
        return result.Success ? result.Value : null;
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<LocalDataService>();
```

For controlling prerendering, you typically adjust this at the application level or use conditional logic within the component to manage rendering (InteractiveServerRenderMode) behaviors, especially for server-side Blazor.

Page.cshtml

```
@page "/"

@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false))

@inject LocalDataService localDataService

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
 await localDataService.StoreLocalDataAsync(Data);
 var result = await localDataService.GetLocalDataAsync<string>(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don’t just say it’s more readable and maintainable, but explain _why_ you believe that. Can you [edit] your answer to provide more detail?